# CQRS+ES: Client log as event

Tags: events, logging, analytics, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm developing small CQRS+ES framework and develop applications with it. In my system, I should log some action of the client and use it for analytics, statistics and maybe in the future do something in domain with it. For example, client (on web) download some resource(s) and I need save date, time, type (download, partial,...), from region or country (maybe IP), etc. after that in some view client can see count of download or some complex report. I'm not sure how to implement this feather.

First solution creates analytic context and some aggregate, in each client action send some command like `IncreaseDownloadCounter(resourced)` them handle the command and raise domain event's and updating view, but in this scenario first download occurred and after that, I send command so this is not really command and on other side version conflict increase.

The second solution is raising event, from client side and update the view model base on it, but in this type of handling my event not store in event store because it's not raise by command and never change any domain context. If is store it in event store, no aggregate to handle it after fetch for some other use.

Third solution is raising event, from client side and I store it on other database may be for each type of event have special table, but in this manner of event handle I have multiple event storage with different schema and difficult on recreating view models and trace events for recreating contexts states so in future if I add some domain for use this type of event's it's difficult to use events.

What is the best approach and solution for this scenario?

Comment: Do you have any business logic to enforce when you are capturing the client events? From your description, it sounds like you just need to save some data to a database and then create some reports - you've not mentioned anything that would require aggregates to enforce business rules. I'd suggest keeping it simple until you *need* to introduce more advanced concepts.

Comment: @tomliversidge Thanks for the reply, now we haven't any business logic enforce, but in the plan of development, we like add something like gamification and that context need it.

You mean at this point I create some log table, client send log and I save it, then in query model interprets log table(s) and generate report? What about performance? I should show the download count in web, so in each request I should huge calculation. If I add some log like count of view it's pretty huge calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First solution creates analytic context and some aggregate

Unquestionably the wrong answer; the event has already happened, so it is too late for the domain model to complain.

What you have is a stream of events.  Putting them in the same event store that you use for your aggregate event streams is fine.  Putting them in a separate store is also fine.  So you are going to need some other constraint to make a good choice.

Typically, reads vastly outnumber writes, so one concern might be that these events are going to saturate the domain store.  That might push you towards storing these events separately from your data model  (prior art: we typically keep the business data in our persistent book of record, but the sequence of http requests received by the server is typically written instead to a log...)

If you are supporting an operational view, push on the requirement that the state be recovered after a restart.  You might be able to get by with building your view off of an in memory model of the event counts, and use something more practical for the representations of the events.

> Thanks for your complete answer, so I should create something like the ES schema without some field (aggregate name or type, version, etc.) and collect client event in that repository, some offline process read and update read model or create command to do something on domain space.

Something like that, yes.  If the view for the client doesn't actually require any validation by your model at all, then building the read model from the externally provided events is fine.

> Are you recommending save some claim or authorization token of the user and sender app for validation in another process?

Maybe, maybe not.  The token describes the authority of the *event*; our own event handler is the authority for the *command(s)* that is/are derived from the events.  It's an interesting question that probably requires more context -- I'd suggest you open a new question on that point.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer, so I should create something like the ES schema without some field (aggregate name or type, version, etc.) and collect client event in that repository, some offline process read and update read model or create command to do something on domain space. Are you recommending save some claim or authorization token of the user and sender app for validation in another process?